# Access web service in PERL

Tags: web-services, perl

I am accessing web service which is hosted in IIS from perl script. I have a methos in service which returns an array of string. I am not able to read the response from service. By using Dumper i printed the response returned by service, and there I can see the array values but I am not able to access the array values. How to access thr array values returned form web service method.
Calling of method in perl:

```
my $method2 = SOAP::Data->name('getCustInfo')->attr({xmlns => 'http://tempuri.org/'});
my @param=(SOAP::Data->name(custId=>$custid));
my $response1= $soap->call($method2=>@param);
print $response1;

print Dumper $response1;

@result11=$response1->result;
print Dumper $response1;
$i=-1;
foreach my $result(@result11)
{
  ++$i;
  print $result[$i];
}
```

The above code I am using to access the method, and I am trying to print it but it not working its giving:  HASH(0x3a84518)$VAR1 = undef;
 What is the problem. 

Thanks,
Avinash

Comment: Please include the Dumper output.

Comment: @user1126070, he did. It's `$VAR1 = undef`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before knowing the response check whether the call happens.

use strict;
    use warnings;

```
use SOAP::Lite +trace=>"debug"; # it debugs whether the connection is set or not

my ($soap,$proxy,$uri);

eval {
    $soap  = new SOAP::Lite
             proxy=>$proxy,
             uri=>$uri;
};

    if ( $@ ){
     print " Service Down\n";
     }
```

For the soap call, it requires the proxy and the uri kindly have those in the eval to check whether they are accessible.

Comment: Caveat to readers: don't use the indirect method call (`new SOAP::Lite`). Direct call (`SOAP::Lite->new(...)`) is almost universally preferred these days.